# Accessing GeoServer on own domain (Windows OS)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, windows

I installed an GeoServer on my laptop with MS Windows installed.

I wish to access a WFS or HTML file through "localhost/geoserver/" rather than "localhost:8080/geoserver/", the WFS file has to be connected to a running GeoServer all the time. In this case I can use my web server running an OpenLayers output file.

Some people suggested to use proxy, but I don't know which configuration file I have to modify and what I should change as well.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: how did you install GeoServer? you can change the port quite easily but it's not really a geographic question

Comment: Do you have IIS installed?